# Angular2 Child-Child Communication

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How do you perform **Child-Child**  communicationin Angular2? The [Angular2 Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) Describes many ways of performing **Parent-Child** communication.  However, How can children *contained* by a parent interact with each other?  Can one child capture an even emitted by another? So far my attempts have failed, and I would like to know if anyone has a good pattern  for Child-Child communication.

For instance, how can I wire these two child components to hear events emitted by each other? This is my attempt so far:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <section>          
      <app-countdown-timer (onResetTimer)="countdownTimerComponent.resetCountDownTimer()"></app-countown-timer>        
      <app-buildplan (onTimedOut)="buildPlan.perfomTimeOutAction()"></app-buildplan>
    </section>
`,
...
})
export class CreateBuildplanComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(BuildPlanComponent) private buildPlan: BuildPlanComponent;
  @ViewChild(CountdownTimerComponent) private countdownTimerComponent:CountdownTimerComponent;
...
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen this explicitly called out anywhere, but I'd expect that you could use the injector at the parent Component level to create an Observable accessible throughout the scope as an event bus.

Comment: @Amy That's a good idea.  I can see how that would be useful in a more complicated use case. Could you post an example?

Comment: Sorry, no, but you might want to search on "Angular 2 Component Event Bus" and see what pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template variables like

```
  <app-countdown-timer #countdown 
    (onResetTimer)="buildplan.resetCountDownTimer()"></app-countown-timer>        
  <app-buildplan #buildplan 
    (onTimedOut)="countdown.perfomTimeOutAction()"></app-buildplan>
```

This example calls an event handler from the sibling. Not sure if this is exactly what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, at least for **Child-Child communication through events**. It turns out that the `onTimedOut` event emitted by the `app-countdown-timer` needs to be listend to in it's own selector, ie `<app-countdown-timer (onTimedOut)="..">`.  The same goes for the the other components.  The `@ViewChild(BuildPlanComponent) private buildPlan: BuildPlanComponent;` in the **parent** class allows access to the "builplan" component in the parent template (ie `(onTimedOut)="buildPlan.perfomTimeOutAction()"`)

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <section>          
      <app-countdown-timer (onTimedOut)="buildPlan.perfomTimeOutAction()"></app-countown-timer>        
      <app-buildplan (onResetTimer)="countdownTimerComponent.resetCountDownTimer()"></app-buildplan>
    </section>
`,
...
})
export class CreateBuildplanComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(BuildPlanComponent) private buildPlan: BuildPlanComponent;
  @ViewChild(CountdownTimerComponent) private countdownTimerComponent:CountdownTimerComponent;
...
}
```